# Approval workflow has status "Rejected" when sent to approver

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, workflow, approval

I use the standard "Publishing approval" workflow on a publishing site with SharePoint 2013.

The issue is, that when an editor sends the item for approval to the content manager, the item has stated: "Rejected".

My first idea was that the editor tries to edit the item after starting the workflow - this is not the case.

What are other possible reasons for this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The task was completed with status "Rejected" but approver didn't complete the task?

It seems that other approvers rejected the task. Could you check workflow history to see who has rejected the task?

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Below find the way where to find it:

1. Open the item
2. On the ribbon click on "PUBLISH" and then Status
3. You will find there "Running workflows" and "Completed workflows".
4. After clicking on the workflow's name you will see datailed information about the workflow history (like in the answer above).

Answer (score 0):

Permission issue? Contribute access does not grant "approve", just add/edit.
"Library Settings" -> "Versioning Settings" -> Require Content Approval for Submitted Items - if "Yes" then contributors can't "approve".

Comment: Hi, the person who is approving the content has permission level "Full control", so in my opinion the permission is OK. The problem is that the approver has to re-start the workflow again because the original workflow is completed with status "Rejected"